# Displaying the name of the user who made a post

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

i am creating a rails app, where I have the functionality that an user can make an account using devise, then post a shipment. I have made it so It can display the shipment, but how to display the first name of the person who made the shipment?

**My views**

```
index.html.erb
<div class="page-header">
<h1>Listing Shipments</h1>
</div>

<%= link_to "Post a new Shipment", new_shipment_path, class: "btn btn-success" %>

<% @shipments.each do |shipment| %>
<div class="shipment">
<h3><strong><%= shipment.user.first_name %></strong></h3>
<h5><strong>DESCRIPTION: </strong><%= shipment.description %></h5>
  <div class="meta">
    <%= link_to time_ago_in_words(shipment.created_at) + " ago" %> |
    <%= link_to "show", shipment %>
    <span class="admin"> 
      | <%= link_to "Edit", edit_shipment_path(shipment) %> |
      <%= link_to "Delete", shipment, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Hey! Are you sure! You wanna delete this shipment??"} %>
  </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

**My shipment controller**

```
class ShipmentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_shipment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  # GET /shipments
  # GET /shipments.json
  def index
    @shipments = Shipment.all
  end

  # GET /shipments/1
  # GET /shipments/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /shipments/new
  def new
    @shipment = Shipment.new
  end

  # GET /shipments/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /shipments
  # POST /shipments.json
  def create
    @shipment = Shipment.new(shipment_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @shipment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @shipment, notice: 'Shipment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @shipment }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @shipment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /shipments/1
  # PATCH/PUT /shipments/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @shipment.update(shipment_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @shipment, notice: 'Shipment was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @shipment }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @shipment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /shipments/1
  # DELETE /shipments/1.json
  def destroy
    @shipment.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to shipments_url, notice: 'Shipment was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_shipment
      @shipment = Shipment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def shipment_params
      params.require(:shipment).permit(:name, :description, :from, :to, :date, :pay)
    end
end
```

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
         has_many :shipments
end
```

**Shipment Model**

```
class Shipment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

After adding `shipment.user.first_name` in my shipment index view file my app is giving error that:

```
undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: the error is because there is a shipment with out user associated to it . try to confirm all shipments have the `user_id` set in it. incase you want to avoid this error on page do this `shipment.user.try(:first_name)` im expecting shipment is having `user_id` in it

Comment: sorry sir am very new to rails am trying to teach myself so i don't know how to set user-id with my shipment model and i had not added anything like user_id in my app

Comment: no problem. first of all i would suggest to please read this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html. this will help you understand how association works. now in current scenario as shipment belongs to user,to find the user for each shipment you need to set the `user_id` inside the `shipments` table. that `user_id` will behave as foreign key in shipment and it will be used to fetch associated user for the shipment. now when some user creates a shipment. you can set the `user_id` like this: `@shipment.user_id = current_user.id` noticing `current_user` is not available in model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to complete the database association by adding a `user_id` column to your `Shipment` model. This can be done through the terminal.

```
rails g migration AddColumnUserIdToShipment user_id:integer
```

Then type the next command

```
rake db:migrate
```

to update the database. Then in your controller change the following line `@shipment = Shipment.new(shipment_params)` to     `@shipment = current_user.shipments.new(shipment_params)`

That will fill in the user_id with the ID of the current user.